# How to suppress debug message on functional test with simple-phpunit

Tags: functional-testing, symfony4

I'm just getting started with Symfony 4 and have this problem.

1. Is it normal to have debugged message printed on a console like this when running the functional test?

```php
$ vendor/bin/simple-phpunit 
PHPUnit 5.7.27 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Testing Functional Controller
2018-03-20T18:51:20+07:00 [debug] Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure".
2018-03-20T18:51:20+07:00 [debug] Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ValidateRequestListener::onKernelRequest".
2018-03-20T18:51:20+07:00 [debug] Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\TestSessionListener::onKernelRequest".
2018-03-20T18:51:20+07:00 [debug] Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest".
2018-03-20T18:51:20+07:00 [debug] Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest".
2018-03-20T18:51:20+07:00 [debug] Listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest" stopped propagation of the event "kernel.request".
2018-03-20T18:51:20+07:00 [debug] Listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\ResolveControllerNameSubscriber::onKernelRequest" was not called for event "kernel.request".
2018-03-20T18:51:20+07:00 [debug] Listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest" was not called for event "kernel.request".
2018-03-20T18:51:20+07:00 [debug] Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse".
2018-03-20T18:51:20+07:00 [debug] Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DataCollector\RequestDataCollector::onKernelResponse".
2018-03-20T18:51:20+07:00 [debug] Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelResponse".
2018-03-20T18:51:20+07:00 [debug] Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\TestSessionListener::onKernelResponse".
2018-03-20T18:51:20+07:00 [debug] Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelResponse".
2018-03-20T18:51:20+07:00 [debug] Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\SaveSessionListener::onKernelResponse".
2018-03-20T18:51:20+07:00 [debug] Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\StreamedResponseListener::onKernelResponse".
2018-03-20T18:51:20+07:00 [debug] Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelFinishRequest".
2018-03-20T18:51:20+07:00 [debug] Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelFinishRequest".
2018-03-20T18:51:20+07:00 [debug] Notified event "kernel.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelTerminate".
F                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 136 ms, Memory: 10.00MB

There was 1 failure:

1) App\Tests\Controller\HomeControllerTest::testHomepage
Failed asserting that 404 matches expected 200.

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1.
```

2. Can it be disabled/suppressed? It seems this message doesn't appear on unit testing.

**Edit**

by adding environment variable into `phpunit.xml` I got it suppressed but now it's showing uncaught exception when testing undefined route.

```
<phpunit>
    ...
    <php>
        <env name="APP_DEBUG" value="false" />
    </php>
    ...
</phpunit>
```

Log

```
$ vendor/bin/simple-phpunit 
PHPUnit 5.7.27 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Testing 
.2018-03-21T11:22:50+07:00 [error] Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /"" at vendor/symfony/http-kernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php line 144
F.
Time: 124 ms, Memory: 8.00MB

There was 1 failure:

1) App\Tests\Controller\HomeControllerTest::testHomepage
Failed asserting that 404 matches expected 200.
...
```

Is it possible to hide this error message?

### Update

It seems this problem occur when I delete `vendor` and `bin` directory in the root project. Trying to re-install all dependencies with `composer install` doesn't fix this problem, so I decide to re-create the project from start. This is the steps that I do :

- create new symfony project with `composer create-project symfony/skeleton my-project-name`
- adding other dependecies such as twig, maker, annotation etc with composer command. I'm not editing `composer.json` directly until all dependecies is installed and there's no problem with functional testing.
- copy `.git` directory from previous project into new 're-created' project to import git history.
- I'm letting composer (symfony recipe) to resolve all configuration, overwrite my previous config.
- resolve other conflict before commiting

I'm letting this qustion open in case there's someone figure it out what's actually happen and how to resolve it without re-creating the project.

Answer (score 0):

has the same issue and it was fixed with:

```
<env name="APP_ENV" value="test" />
```

in phpunit.xml file